# How does Morgan know so much personal information about strangers?

Tags: plot-explanation, morgan

Minor spoilers ahead, but nothing that I think takes away from the plot.

In the movie Morgan (2016) there are several scenes where Morgan knows a fair bit of information about people she's never met before.

> Like Lee Weathers, the corporate risk manager, who was sent to evaluate her.  How did she know her name before they were introduced?

or

> Dr. Shapiro and knowing he had a 13 year old daughter (I think it was a daughter).  And it came off as being his first visit there and no one knew anything about him.

Being that she was locked up, it did not look like she had a lot of access to outside information.  And I do not think that the casual conversations she might have had with the other employees would have garnered her that data.

So, did I miss something, or how would she have known anything about the newcomers?

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot of detailed, explicit information about what actually is going-on with Morgan -- seemingly because of a bit of realism injected into the plot, since these scientists are still studying her and don't fully understand her abilities or limitations.

Morgan seems to be able to "see" people watching her through security cameras, and as you ask about, she seems to know things she couldn't know.

Ultimately, it's revealed that Lee is the result of a similar, previous experiment, but that in her design, they purposefully avoided emotionality and tried to target characteristics of loyalty, efficiency, and goal-driven sensibilities. This also isn't overly explained, but comes up quickly at the very end as the executives are talking.

The difference with Morgan was that they tried to ratchet-up "empathy" in her "design", and see if they could create this hybrid-human super-soldier that was even more self-reliant, adaptive, and capable. The executives talk about a feeling that the "Lee" design is good, but too cold and blunt and doesn't adapt very well, so they were trying to experiment.

Again, it's not really explained, but by reusing tropes from other movies (facing into a security camera like you can see who's watching, or knowing information you couldn't possibly know) they seem to be hinting at the idea that pushing for more "empathy" actually leaned hard towards "telepathy" and Extra-sensory Perception (ESP). They're basically suggesting that Morgan was still developing, but was becoming hyper-aware and actually verging towards reading minds, but it all seemed more instinctual than purposeful.

Since they get shutdown quickly, they never really got to explore where she was going with her evolution, so there's not a clear answer of where she was at.

Comment: I like the idea of her "sophisticated emotional responses_" growing into something more ESP-like.  And since they never explain what the "nano" is that they put in her, maybe it also grew with her and allowed her to link to the electronics around her, like the camera, and eavesdrop - becoming a not-yet-conscious Sherlock Holmes in reading people.  I'll have to find and read the script to see it garners anything more.